# Importing settings files from settings.py gives ImportException 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined'

Tags: django, debugging

I'm trying to create different settings files for my development and production servers. So, in `settings.py` I call:

```
try:
    from localsettings import *
except ImportError, e:  
    print "import error", e
    pass
```

Then, in `localsettings.py`, I set the variables. However, this results in an ImportError when I run `syncdb` with message:

> Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

I can't say that I understand what the problem is - if I move the exact same settings back to the original `settings.py` file, everything works fine. Can anyone please tell me what obvious thing I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're not importing something strange. I remember one time, I had the following statement:

```
import django.contrib.auth.backends
```

for use in an `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` variable. But since that import seems to require a completely loaded settings file, it failed and I received a similar error message.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it was an import issue in the end - thanks.